# Under which condition we can use semi-classical approach in non-interacating bosons system?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, semiclassical

I am studying BEC and interacting Bosons system. I take Bose-Einstein condensation in dilute gases (C. J. Pethick, H. Smith) as my reference. In section 2.3.1, they mentioned:

$$
n(\vec{r})=\sum_{\nu}|\phi_{\nu}(\vec{r})|^2f_{\nu}
$$

, where $f_{v}=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon_{\nu}-\mu)}-1}$, $\phi_{\nu}(\vec{r})$ are the energy eigenstates. $n(\vec{r})$ is number density. Now they mentioned that a particle can not be specified with arbitrary accuracy. They must obey Heisenburg uncertainty principal, $\Delta x\Delta p\geq h$. So the number of states in terms of classical phase space is: $\frac{d\vec{p}d\vec{r}}{h^3}.$ And this is possible to write $f_{\nu}$ as $f_{\vec{p}}(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon_{\vec{p}}(\vec{r})-\mu)}-1}.$

They mention when properties of interest do not require information about the
particle distribution on position and momentum that violate Heisenburg uncertainty principle, semi-classical approach is possible.

I feel vague about their description. Under which condition is called that we don't need the information about the particle distribution on position and momentum that violate Heisenburg uncertainty principle? Normally, because of the noncommunity of position and momentum operator, the position and momentum of any particle must obey Heisenburg uncertainty principle.

Can someone understand this and give an example?

Thanks